# Recover non-normalized solutions from NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

Are there certain commands, or some mathematical trick I can use to recover the non-normalized solutions from NDEigensystem?

My equation of interest is of the form

$u''(x)+f(x)u(x)=\lambda u(x)$

I need the non-normalized functions and I'm not sure how to find them. I can't just insert $au(x)$ into my equation since the normalization constant would divide out.

Would my best option be to solve this equation again in NDSolve and explicitly insert the eigenvalue?

Comment: You can multiply a normalized eigenfunction by any arbitrary constant to obtain a non-normalized eigenfunction.  In other words, non-normalized eigenfunctions are not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You are looking for the option `"VectorNormalization"`. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4, 
   Method -> {"VectorNormalization" -> None}];

NIntegrate[#^2, {x, 0, \[Pi]}] & /@ funs
{0.07662421106316575`, 0.07479974990831867`, 0.07479782758346251`, \
0.0747915351146286`}
```

The default is to normalize with respect to the system matrices:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4, 
   Method -> {"VectorNormalization" -> 
      Function[{values, vectors, stiffness, damping},
       s = stiffness; d = damping;
       norm = 
        vectors/Diagonal[
           vectors.damping.ConjugateTranspose[vectors]]^(1/2)]}];
```

The functions are constructed by interpolating the eigenvectors:

```
Max[Abs[#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ funs - norm]]
0.`
```